# Tab Activity Swipe Direction

Tags: android

i have a question about Tab Activity.
How can i reverse the direction of Changing Tab like Whatsapp application. there are some tabs
 [ **1**   2   3 ]
  we are current in 1, when user swipe **from right to left**, the tab goes to 2.
  [ 1   **2**   3 ]
Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: what is your question exactly

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Aaakash See Whatsapp application swipe

Comment: use tab layout and viewpager check this link,it´s very easy http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/